# How to create a new column in a dataframe with a parsed value from another column where condition is satisfied

Tags: python, parsing

Here is an example:

```
cars2 = {'Brand': ['Hon*da\nCivic', 'BM^AMT^B6^278.99\n'],
        'Price': [22000, 55000]
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(cars2, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

delim = '^'
```

Output:

```
                Brand  Price
0       Hon*da\nCivic  22000
1  BM^AMT^B6^278.99\n  55000
```

I need:

```
                Brand  Price Allowed Amount
0       Hon*da\nCivic  22000              0
1  BM^AMT^B6^278.99\n  55000         278.99
```

I tried:

```
for field in range(0, len(df2)):
    if 'AMT'+delim+'B6' in df2.iloc[field]['Brand']:
                df2.iloc[field]['Allowed_Amount'] = df2.iloc[field]['Brand'].split("AMT"+delim+"B6")[1][1:].split('\n')[0]
    else:
        df2.iloc[field]['Allowed_Amount'] = 0
```

It gives me this error:

```
__main__:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

How can i fix this? If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 df2['Allowed_Amount'] = df2['Brand'].str.split('^',-1).str[3]
 df2['Allowed_Amount'] = df2['Allowed_Amount'].str[:-2]
```

You can also make it one line:

```
df2['Allowed_Amount'] = df2['Brand'].str.split('^',-1).str[3].str[:-2]
```

The first line will split the "^" by doing from last and get the last value. Then in second line we removing the new line !